# NSDictionary Coding-Compliant

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have this code which checks if the user inputted something into the username and password textfield and the password in the password textfield matches the one in the confirm password textfield:

```
- (IBAction)createAccountButton:(id)sender {
    if([self.createPasswordTextField.text isEqualToString:self.confirmPasswordTextField.text] && self.createPasswordTextField.text.length != 0 && self.createUserNameTextField.text.length != 0){
        NSDictionary *userAccountDetails = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
        [userAccountDetails setValue:self.createUserNameTextField.text forKey:@"username"];
        [userAccountDetails setValue:self.createPasswordTextField forKey:@"password"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:self.users forKey:@"users"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
        [self.users addObject:userAccountDetails];
    }else{
        UIAlertView *passwordMismatchAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Passwords do not match!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [passwordMismatchAlert show];
    }
}
```

For some reason every time I click on the createAccountButton, I get an error in Xcode saying: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key username.' I made sure that my IB outlets are not broken since many other posts pointed that out. So I am not really sure what is going on in this method. Any insight?

Answer (score 2):

You should use `NSMutableDictionary` and `setObject:forKey:`

```
 NSMutableDictionary * dic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[dic setObject:yourobj forKey:yourkey];
```

So in your code

```
 NSMutableDictionary *userAccountDetails = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[userAccountDetails setObject:self.createUserNameTextField.text forKey:@"username"];
[userAccountDetails setObject:self.createPasswordTextField forKey:@"password"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:self.users forKey:@"users"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
[self.users addObject:userAccountDetails];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your User class needs to implement the NSCoding protocol https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCoding_Protocol/